# embedded command resulting in argument of \equal has extra } error

Tags: math-mode, macros, errors, conditionals, ifthenelse

I am trying to make a macro (`\ls`) which will convert keywords into the mathmode version of their equivalent logic symbol. I've figured a way to make this work fine, except when it is in an argument of another function (`\bda` which organizes arguments into a lambda calculus function), in which case it will give me a

> `argument of \equal has extra }`

error. Note that if only the first two lines in the main document are used, they both result in the correct output, whereas only a situation like the third line causes this error.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin = 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\mm}[1]{$#1$}
\newcommand{\ifis}[4]{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{#2}}{#3}{#4}}
\newcommand{\mmifis}[4]{\ifis{#1}{#2}{\mm{#3}}{#4}}

\newcommand{\ls}[1]%
{\mmifis    {#1}    {and}
            {\land}
{\mmifis    {#1}    {or}
            {\lor}
{\mmifis    {#1}    {in}
            {\in}
{\mmifis    {#1}    {subset}
            {\subseteq}
{\mmifis    {#1}    {psubset}
            {\subset}
{\mmifis    {#1}    {not}
            {\neg}
{\mmifis    {#1}    {exists}
            {\exists}
{\mmifis    {#1}    {forall}
            {\forall}
{???}}}}}}}}}

\begin{document}

\ls{and}
\bda{z}{e}{$\land$}{k}
\bda{z}{e}{\ls{and}}{k}

\end{document}
```

What exactly is causing this, and how do I fix it, not just for this instance, but for potential instances down the road?

Comment: please provide a test file that shows the problem, as posted it just shows an undefined command error for `\bda` the error you report is not due to something being in an argument it depends what `\bda` tries to do with its arguments.

Comment: If you could consider using land and lor as inputs, your command could be made much shorter using \expandafter\csname#1\endcsname and a simple \ifdefined check. In particular you could avoid using the ifthen package.

Comment: Without knowing what `\bda` does, it's impossible to tell what's going wrong. Please, add the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to your `ifthenelse` macro, which does not require any package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\ls}[1]{\begingroup\let\or\lor% locally redefine \or
\let\and\land% locally redefine \and
\let\oldsubset\subset% mess around with subset
\let\psubset\oldsubset% 
\let\subset\subseteq%
\ifcsname #1\endcsname%
\ensuremath{\expandafter\csname #1\endcsname}%
\else
???%
\fi\endgroup}
\begin{document}
 $\ls{and}\ls{or}\ls{subset}\ls{psubset}\ls{wurzelbrumpf}$
\end{document}
```

[image]